# live asp.net web.config settings

Tags: asp.net, security, web-config

I've only recently started working with asp.net and c#. Is there a standard practice set of web.config settings for a live final website? There seem to be a ton of options available and I'm looking to streamline performance, close possible security holes and other unnecessary options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tip/Trick: Automating Dev, QA, Staging, and Production Web.Config Settings with VS 2005](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/21/tip-trick-automating-dev-qa-staging-and-production-web-config-settings-with-vs-2005.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

An empty web.config (or at least an absent *`<`system.web>* element) would mean that all of the framework's recommended defaults would take effect. You would then just need to be concerned with the host (e.g., IIS) set-up.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a clean web.config and only add the sections you need.

For security, all you really can do is make sure you flag 
    <compelation debug="false">
 for your production box and set custom errors to true.

Answer (score 1):

Secure all folders containing any sensitive info with the location tag. Encrypt any connection strings with [DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998280.aspx).